# How can write a list as a formatted string to a file

Tags: export

I have two lists:

`{a, 1, b}` and `{b, 1.3, y}`

My goal is to print them to file `test.dat`, so that the content of `test.dat` looks like:

```
(a 1 b)
(b 1.300 y)
```

I want the elements of the lists in the output file to be separated by spaces.

**Questions:**

1. How can I do it?
2. Is it possible to use Print command to do it?

**Edit 1:**

I was going along these lines:

```
myPrint[list_] := Print["(", Row[list, " "], ")"]
l1 = {a, 1, b};
myPrint[l1]
```

> (a 1 b)

My problem is that I don't know how to export the results I got to a file. So this is the reason for my question 2.

**Edit Final: Problem Solved**

Solution by **swish** (from comments)

```
str = OpenWrite["test.dat"]
myPrint[list_] :=
  WriteString[str, Row[{"(", Row[NumberForm[#, {4, 3}] & /@ list, " "], ")\n"}]]
l1 = {a, 1, b}
myPrint[l1]
```

Comment: You've seen `Export[]`?

Comment: @J.M., thank you for your comment. Yes, I did, but it has some predefined format of output (for example, column output - each element of the list is being output on a new line). What I want is control over the output format. I got the idea how to get this control using Print function, but have no clue how to output (Export?) results of the Print function to file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some tweaks to your function and you done:

```
myPrint[list_] := 
 ToString[Row[{"(", Row[NumberForm[#, {4, 3}] & /@ list, " "], ")"}]]
```

Now it returns string and you can `Export` it.

Comment: thank you very much! This solves my problem! Still, I've got one more question: I read that Print outputs to \$Output. It seems that if I set \$Output to some file, Print will do the job without necessity to transform output into String. Does anyone know how to set \$Output to output to file test.dat?

Comment: @user1541776 Use `OpenWrite` to open your file and `Write` to it instead of `Print`.

Comment: thank you once again! The problem is that it outputs into file "Row[{"(", Row[{NumberForm[a, {4, 3}], NumberForm[1, {4, 3}], 
    NumberForm[b, {4, 3}]}, " "], ")"}]" rather than (a 1 b), i.e. in some sense outputs the expression and not the result of the evaluation of expression. (Tried to add Evaluat[] - it didn't help).

Comment: @user1541776 `WriteString` then :).

Comment: thank you, it worked! You made my day :-)

Comment: @user1541776 don't forget to upvote answers that you found helpful

Comment: @cormullion I will come back to up vote as soon as I earn reputation 15.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple and inelegant way. Define a function that places the information in the desired text-string form.

```
string[x_]:="("~~ToString[x[[1]]]~~" "~~ToString[x[[2]]]~~" "~~ToString[x[[3]]] ~~ ")"
```

and then Export

```
 Export["test.txt", {string[x], string[z]}]
```

where

```
x = {a, 1, b}
z = {b, 1.3, y}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. There are two things I need: 1. I would like to print lists with arbitrary number of elements (not necessarily 3 as I specified in my example) 2. I would like to have more control over printed numbers - floats to be output in %f4.3 format rather than %f2.1.

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on `StringReplace` and `Export` and with number format control:

```
x = {a, 1, b}
z = {b, 1.3, y, 4}

(* replace brackets and braces *)
   sr[x_] := StringReplace[
  ToString@(x /. y_?NumericQ -> NumberForm[y, {3, 4}]), {","->" ", "{"->"(", "}"->")"}]

(* Export a collection of your expressions to a file *)
Export["/tmp/test.tmp", sr /@ {x, z, x, z}, "Table"]
```