# Write list of numbers to a file

Tags: list-manipulation, export, file-transfer

I have a list of numbers:

e.g.    `list={1,2,3,4,5}`

To write the list to a file I use (here each integer number occupies 7 spaces):

```
WriteString[file, 
  Row[{Row[PaddedForm[#, 7] & /@ list, " "], "\n"}]];
```

(I took the proposal from: [How can write a list as a formatted string to a file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23536/how-can-write-a-list-as-a-formatted-string-to-a-file))

Is there also another solution to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it with `PaddedForm`:

```
Export["filepath.txt", 
 StringJoin[ToString@PaddedForm[#, 6] & /@ {-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

This works with negative numbers as well. Will work the same with `WriteString`.

If you want more control over the padding, you can use your own function...

```
custompad[num_, padlength_?IntegerQ] := StringPadLeft[ToString@num,padlength]
SetAttributes[custompad, Listable]


str = OpenWrite[]
WriteString[str, StringJoin@custompad[RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, 20], 7]]
Close[str]

FilePrint[%]
```

> `-17    -35    -38    -64     88     34     23   -100      2     55
>   84    -11    -46    -87    -46    -86    -53     35     -6    -50`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you are after, but this is how I always import / export long lists:

*Export*

```
Export["C:\\Directory\\list.txt", list]
```

*Import*

```
list = ToExpression[Import["C:\\Directory\\list.txt", "List"]];
```